# Unable to get variables from a seperate class on the .aspx page using @Import Namespace=

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, import

I have an ASP.net web application using C# as the back end. I have a class of Unique Variables that I want to access on my .aspx page.

I saw a great example on how to do this at the Microsoft site:  https://forums.asp.net/t/2127062.aspx?How+to+access+the+class+declared+Public+Variable+to+ASPX+Page+

Here is my partial code for Action.aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Action.aspx.cs" Inherits="Admin_Test Action" %>

<% @Import Namespace="TestClass" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
```

and the TestClass.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Admin_Test
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public string ItemType = "TEST VALUE";
    }
}
```

In the .aspx page, I am importing the class via the class name. However, when I run the code, I get the message "The type or namespace name 'TestClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The TestClass.cs file is located in the same folder as the Action.aspx/Action.aspx.cs files. It should see it, but for some reason does not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Eric

Addendum- Failing code for response to Orvar...

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Action.aspx.cs" Inherits="Admin_Test.Visual.Content.Action" %>

<% @Import Namespace="Admin_Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>

    <%-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7, chrome=1"/>--%>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/ui/ui.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/ui/ui.datepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="itemtypes/CommonCSS/valueadded.css" />
    <link type="text/css" href="../js/ui/themes/base/ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var bValid = false;

        var ItemType = UniqueVar.itemtype;
```

The File name of the class is UniqueVar. Its Class name is UniqueVar. Its Namespace is Admin_Test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to add the namespace instead of the class name to the import like the following:

```
<% @Import Namespace="Admin_Test" %>
```

Could perhaps instead get the value like the following. By putting the value in the page´s codebehind file:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected string ItemType;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ItemType = "TEST VALUE";
    }
}

<script type="text/javascript">
     ////Getting variable from asp.net code behind  
      alert("<%=ItemType%>");
</script>
```

Comment: Thank You. I did a quick test and it seemed to work. I can confirm on Monday when I am back at work.

Comment: Orvar, It did not work. I have posted the failing .aspx code to the original post. In Visual Studios, when I type UniqueVar. intellisense sees everything in that class, including itemtype. However, When I run my code, I get an error, 'UniqueVar' is undefined.  I am not sure I understand why this is happening, as V.S sees the class.  Any Ideas?

Comment: Hmmm can you post the actual error message? Thx.

Comment: What if you create a get property, perhaps that would work.. like `public string ItemType{ get; set; }`

Comment: Same problem using getters and setters. The actual error message is 'UniqueVar' is undefined, line 30, which is the line: var ItemType = UniqueVar.itemtype;

Comment: I am trying to get values from the aspx.cs page on the .aspx page. I do this by declaring public variables in the Class section of the aspx.cs page. This works fine, as Those variables can be accessed by the .aspx page. The problem is when there is a page change, the code iterates through the class again and reinitialized the public variables. There is no query string to refresh these public variables, so their value is lost.  I thought if I create a separate class with variables on a separate .cs page, the variables wouldn't get wipes. How do I access those variables on the .aspx page?

Comment: Sorry matey, not sure what the problem is :/ Have you looked at SessionState? Or perhaps save the value in a database?

Comment: I could store the values in session state, but how do I get them on  the .aspx page?

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can add the variable in the pages codebehind file and access it in the html with the code I added. Please give it a go and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank You iceCode, "add the variable in the pages codebehind file and access it in the html" is exactly what i did.

Comment: IceCode, How do I mark the answer as useful? I can up vote, and I accepted  your answer (green check mark), but don't see any other options to mark as useful.